# Add optgroups to angular-selectize asynchronously

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, selectize.js

I am using [angular-selectize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-selectize2) directive in my project. For this, I need to load optgroups asynchronously. So far I have tried multiple approaches but none of them works. The problem is, you cannot use the data returned by a promise synchronously. On the flip side, I have also been unable to initialize selectize from inside a promise callback. Given below is the code I currently have. Note that it is only to be used to get the idea of the data I'm playing with, not to present it as something you can consider right.

**app.js**

```
$http
.get('/get-categories')
.then(getCategoriesSCB, getCategoriesFCB);
function getCategoriesSCB(response) {
  if(typeof(response.data) === 'object') {
    posControl.menuCategories = response.data[0];
    posControl.menuCategoryGroups = response.data[1];
  }
  else {
    getCategoriesFCB(response);
  }
}
function getCategoriesFCB(response) {
  console.log(response);
}

posControl.menuConfig = {
  valueField: 'id',
  labelField: 'title',
  placeholder: 'Select Category',
  optgroupField: 'class',
  optgroupLabelField: 'label',
  optgroupValueField: 'value',
  optgroups: posControl.menuCategoryGroups,
  maxItems: 1,
  searchField: ['title', 'category'],
  onInitialize: function(selectize) {
    console.log('selectize is here');
  },
}
```

**index.html**

```
<selectize config="POSCtrl.menuConfig" options="POSCtrl.menuCategories" ng-model="POSCtrl.menuModel"></selectize>
```

**data returned by ajax call**

```
[
    // this array has to be used for options.
    [{
        "class": "57b83830babb9",
        "category": "Food Menu",
        "id": "57b83855b23f9",
        "title": "Beverages"
    }, {
        "class": "57b83830babb9",
        "category": "Food Menu",
        "id": "57b83855c05de",
        "title": "Cuisines"
    }, {
        "class": "57b83830babb9",
        "category": "Food Menu",
        "id": "57b83855cdcb4",
        "title": "Steaks"
    }, {
        "class": "57b83830d0899",
        "category": "Wholesale Coffee",
        "id": "57b83830d0899",
        "title": "Wholesale Coffee"
    }],
    // this array has to be used for optgroups
    [{
        "value": "57b83830babb9",
        "label": "Food Menu"
    }, {
        "value": "57b83830d0899",
        "label": "Wholesale Coffee"
    }]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to load a selectize asynchronously by setting the values directly on the posControl.menuConfig:

```
function getCategoriesSCB(response) {
  if (typeof(response.data) === 'object') {
    posControl.menuConfig.options = response.data[0];
    posControl.menuConfig.optgroups = response.data[1];
  }
}
```